# TypeScript Redux

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I started doing the typing of my redux and ran into such a problem, namely the typing of useSelector

Here is the hook I'm creating:

```
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {RootState} from '../store/create-reducer'

export const UseTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook <RootState> = useSelector
```

And he returns me an error:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7VdY.png)

How to solve this problem? For the second day I can't get off the ground, and using `useSelector ((state: any) => state? .SESSION)` is not an option.

Here is my side:

create-reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { STATE } from '../session/types'
import { reducer } from '../session/reducers'

const rootReducer = (asyncReducers: object) => {
  return (
    combineReducers({
      ...asyncReducers,
      [STATE]: reducer,
    })
  )
}

export default rootReducer

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

create-store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import persistStore from './persist-store'
import persistReducer from './persist-reducer'

const store = (initialState = {}) => {
  const middlewares = [thunk]
  const enhancers: Array<any> = []

  const store = createStore(
    persistReducer({}),
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares), ...enhancers),
  )

  const persistor = persistStore(store)

  return { store, persistor }
}

export default store
```

index:

```
export { default as createReducer } from './create-reducer'
export { default as createStore } from './create-store'
export { default as persistReducer } from './persist-reducer'
```

persist-reducer:

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import createReducer from './create-reducer'

const persistConfig = { key: 'myproject', storage, whitelist: ['session'] }

const reducer = (asyncReducers: any) => persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer(asyncReducers))

export default reducer
```

persist-store:

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'

const store = (store: any) => persistStore(store, null, () => {})

export default store
```

Comment: `combineReducers` returns a reducer, not state, the type you need is the type of state, try moving `type RootState` to the store, it should look like `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>`

Comment: Also, when adding TypeScript it might be a good time to revisit the current recommentations and take a look at modern Redux with Redux Toolkit - using RTK, you will only write a very small portion of types, compared to "vanilla" redux, which requires you to write Action Types, Action Type Unions and all that stuff. And of course, it is already a lot less code even before that.

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux